# Passing an Array Parameter In FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to create a custom control that stores a list of images. Ideally in the FXML file I could instantiate my control by passing an argument that is a list of file paths to said images.

I have gotten the control to load from FXML just fine here is the constructor

```
public Gallery(@NamedArg("images") List<String> images) {
    this.imageQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(images);
    this.load("gallery.fxml");
    this.scrollImage();
}
```

Here is the FXML that loads it

```
<Gallery fx:id="contentPane" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="600.0">
      <images>
          1.png,
          2.png,
          3.png
      </images>
  </Gallery>
```

Loads without issue, but there are no images and doing some simple prints I see that instead of creating a list with three values of 1.png,2.png,3.png it creates a list with 1 value of "1.png, 2.png, 3.png"

So my question is how do I get this to instantiate as a list with 3 separate values in it?

Comment: I really do not think that would be "ideal."

Comment: Not sure why you"re using a `PriorityQueue` there, but it"s probably not the best choice...

Comment: [mcve] please .

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach would work with readonly list properties, but there are pieces of information that are not provided with this kind of fxml:

- Which implementation of `List` should be used?
- How many strings are there and where to seperate them; how to tell whether you want a list containing `"1.png,\n          2.png,\n          3.png"`, `"1.png,", "\n          2.png,\n          3.png"` or something else?

It is possible to do something like this, but you need to modify the structure of your fxml:

```xml
<?import java.util.ArrayList?>
<?import java.lang.String?>

...

<Gallery fx:id="contentPane" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <images>
        <ArrayList>
          <String fx:value="1.png" />
          <String fx:value="2.png" />
          <String fx:value="3.png" />
        </ArrayList>
    </images>
</Gallery>
```